# Speed of a river

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, relative-motion

I've got a problem (Sorry if it's too basic). It is:
Going upstream in a canoe, the passengers throw an empty bottle. They keep rowing for 60 minutes, and move 2 kilometers upstream. They then start going back and reach the bottle which has been moving with the currennt 5 km from the point they started going back. If we suppose they have rowed with constant speed, what is the speed of the river?

I started using algebraic tools but I don't seem to organize it very well...

Comment: Any other information we need to know?

Comment: There is no more info. Is it needed?

Comment: No. Just making sure.

Comment: @Inquisitive: Are you aware that the [current homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/715/50583) declares asking for the mere *solution* of homework-like problems off-topic *and* strongly discourages giving complete answers to them?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I won't give a complete answer...if any.

Comment: Sorry if it seemed like that, I'm not asking for the complete answer. I didn't read that section, unfortunately (Now I'm doing it).

Comment: @DavidMolano You're also encouraged to make some attempt to answer it yourself in the question and ask where you're going wrong, or to ask more specific questions.  We expect to see a little effort from your side before we put effort into answering your homework problems.  It's okay if your "algebraic tools" are not well organized; we'd be very happy to explain how to organize them.

Comment: @DavidMolano Try this David. The instant the bottle hits the water, it travels downstream relative to the shore at $V_{stream}$. It travels a distance X in the time it takes the canoe to move 2km. It then travels a distance Y in the time it takes the canoe to turn around and meet up. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

In the moment the bottle falls to the water, it travels downstream at $v_{stream}$. It travels a distance $X=v_{stream}∗1h$ in the first hour and a distance $Y=v_{stream}∗t$ in the unknown time t. Furthermore, $3km=X+Y=v_{stream}(1+t)$. About the canoe, it traveled $2km$ in the first hour, and in the following time $t$ it traveled back $5km$. So it traveled at $2km/h$ the first hour and $5km/t$ the rest of the time.
Furthermore, since $v_{Total_{1}}=v_{canoe}-v_{stream}=2km/h$, and $v_{total_{2}}=v_{canoe}+v_{stream}=5km/t$ (In the other direction), we have
$(v_{canoe}+v_{stream})t=5km$
We have then $v_{canoe}=2km/h+v_{stream}$ and $(2km/h+2v_{stream})t=5km$.
Then $t=\frac{5}{2v_{stream}+2}$, and as $3km=v_{stream}(1+t)$ we have:
$3km=v_{stream}(1+\frac{5}{2v_{stream}+2})$. And this equation is easily solved.
If we take $v=v_{stream}$, we have $0=v(2v+7)-6v-6=2v^2+v-6$. This equation has as zeros $3/2$ and $-2$, and the only one that works is $3/2$.

Comment: No. Forget about $V_{men}$.

Comment: And remember that the canoe must overcome $V_{stream}$ before the canoe can have any upstream velocity relative to the shoreline.

Comment: Another hint: $V_{canoe}-V_{stream} = 2km/hour$

Comment: I restarted like this:
"In the moment the bottle falls to the water, it travels downstream at $v_{stream}$. It travels a distance $X=v_{stream}*1h$ in the first hour and a distance $Y=v_{stream}*t$ in the unknown time $t$. Furthermore, $3km=X+Y=v_{stream}(1+t)$.
About the canoe, it traveled $2km$ in the first hour, and in the following time $t$ it traveled back $5km$. So it traveled at $2km/h$ the first hour and $5km/t$ the rest of the time". Edit: I now see, that your $v_{canoe}$ was my $v_{men}$.

Comment: Another hint: $5km = (V_{canoe}+V_{stream})T$. Good night and good luck. Draw a diagram about what is taking place. You are not there yet.

Comment: Thanks, it's solved. I just used $v_{canoe}=2km/h+v_{stream}$ in the last hint, and after that isolated $t$ and replaced in the $3km=v_{stream}(1+t)$.

And the answer is $3/2$ (I had already the answer, I had problems getting to it).

Comment: Post your solution buddy.